# Why was this post deleted and no reason given?

Tags: discussion

## Why was this post deleted and no reason given?

**Here is the original question:**
[Is Kurt Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem a "cheap trick"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/210/is-kurt-g%c3%b6dels-incompleteness-theorem-a-cheap-trick)

Wittgenstein seems to think that Gödel's G (that he calls P) that is neither provable nor refutable in Russell's system is simply untrue in Russell's system.

The Liar Paradox is also neither provable nor refutable thus making it untrue, and not a truth bearer.

[image]